# Find values in JSON with Ansible without knowing where it is

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

I am trying to find a way to parse below json and get the list of `city` for all items with `"type": "location"`. The challenge is **I don't always know the key names** such as `us`, `john` and `location1` and `location2` in the example below. I have tried to use json_query and regex_search without success.

```
{
    "client": {
        "us": {
            "john": {
                "job": {
                    "type": "job",
                    "job": "waiter"
                },
                "location1": {
                    "type": "location",
                    "address": {
                        "street": "Main St",
                        "city": "Seattle"
                    }
                },                
                "location2": {
                    "type": "location",
                    "address": {
                        "street": "2nd ave",
                        "city": "New York"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the variable `my_data` the task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_data|
                 json_query(query1)|
                 flatten|
                 json_query(query2)
                 }}"
      vars:
        query1: "*.*.*.*"
        query2: "[?type=='location'].address.city"
```

gives the list

```yaml
    "msg": [
        "Seattle",
        "New York"
    ]
```

Very probably the queries can be concatenated.